# Problems with a while-loop

Tags: c

I want when I hit my first button (0x01) go inside the while-loop and start the timer. But I want to print in my console "Hi" everytime I hit the second button 0x02 inside the while-loop. But the program is not printing "Hi". It's just counting the timer.

```
int main(void)
{
    int button=0, button_2=0;

    while(1)
    {
        button = 0x01
        button_2 = 0x02

        if(button==0)
        {

            while(1)
            {

                if(button_2==0)
                {
                printf("Hi");
                }

                    if (seconds<=59)
                    {
                    printf("Seconds = %d\n", seconds);
                    }
                         else
                         {
                         minutes++;
                         seconds=0;
                         printf("Minutes = %d\n", minutes);
                         }

            }
        }


    } return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does it do the counter?  First you `button = 0x01;` and then you `if(button==0)` which can never be true because button = 1.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. There are some missing semi-colons.

Comment: Where do you check for a button press? Just because you named a variable `button` doesn't mean it will automatically contain the state of a button. Explain to me why you think your code works. Where is the variable `seconds` declared? What makes it contain anything other than 0? Your question is impossible to answer without a [mre].

Comment: Everything works, the only thing which not work is if(button_2==0). So I actually dont know why the rest of the code is relevant for you?

Comment: @Harman Where is the code that sets `button_2` to zero? Where is the code that keeps the loops from having too quickly so that there's a second?

Comment: Nothing in your code limits the rate at which "Seconds" and "Minutes" are printed. Are you sure that the "Hi" didn't just scroll off the screen before you saw it? Also, nothing increments the variable `seconds`, so I don't see how you can say that the rest of the code works. In short the site rules require that questions seeking debugging help must include a [mcve], and this question is a good example why.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` function is line buffered by default. Either print entire lines of call `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`.

Comment: He has a newline at the end of the printf string.  Is that what you meant by "print entire lines" or did you mean something else?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah He doesn't have a newline after the `Hi` and he's reporting that the timer is counting but `Hi` isn't being printed. That means either `button_2==0` is `false` or it's the buffering issue. He hasn't shown us how his buttons work, so all I can do is assume they're not the issue.

Comment: The timer is counting, so the first if(button==0) is good. But the second if(button_2==0) is not working. The program is still counting but not printing "Hi".

Comment: This is definitely not the answer. After printing `"Hi"`, the code immediately prints either `"Seconds = %d\n"` or `"Minutes = %d\n"`. So it's not possible for the timer output to appear without `"Hi"` being output first.

Comment: @user3386109 It's hard to be sure because the code shown isn't the actual code. The code shown won't count seconds, which the OP says the code is doing.